# What does an underscore at the beginning of a JS chain mean

Tags: javascript, identifier

What does an underscore at the beginning of a chain mean in Javascript?  For example the value of the template property below:

```
EmProjectItem = Views.PostItem.extend({
            tagName: 'li',
            className: 'project-item',
            template: _.template($('#employer-project-item').html())
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just a variable (or rather a property) named `_`. It means exactly the same as `foo` or `bar`.

Presumably, it is defined by some library such as [underscore.js](/questions/tagged/underscore.js) (care to guess where this library got its name from?) or [lodash](/questions/tagged/lodash).

Answer (score 0):

The underscore is valid for the name of a variable in javascript so it really isn't possible based on the provided code to tell you what the underscore in your example refers to.  I would guess the code is using the underscore.js library given the syntax you provided.

For example, this is perfectly valid:

```
    function foo() {
        var _ = "test";
        alert(_);
    }
```

Here is a link to the underscore.js library for use with it's template function:
http://underscorejs.org/#template